# Meteor 1.3 collection reference error

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections

Meteor 1.3:
My project architecture is:

- .meteor
- both

  - articles.js
  - tags.js
    ...
- client

  - templates
  - - templates.html
  - - templates.js
- server

  - main.js

I want to use my collection both for some checks in client and in server so for that i use:

```
import { CollectionName } from "path/to/Collection"
```

both on client side and server side

In collection file I have:

```
export const CollectionName = new Mongo.Collection("collection");
```

I've tried with global.Collection name, without any word before collection name like it was before Meteor 1.3 -> still get :

```
Exception from sub articles id 2irSGEkWinCGvB33z ReferenceError: Articles is not defined
```

If I use just `import './../both/collections/collectionName';` I get  CollectionName is not defined;

Comment: Where is your collection file located?

Comment: in both folder, also tried to move it to lib in just one collections.js file not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `import`, you'll need to put your code under the `imports` directory. See the [application structure](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) section of the guide. In particular, read the [file structure](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure) section for an example layout.